Nextjs formData
I'm sending a post request from postman to send a image file through formData.
//code part

const res = await request.formData()
const videoUrl = res.get("video_url");
console.log(videoUrl); 


log output-> File {


    size: 12744143,
    type: 'video/mp4',
    name: 'test.mp4',
    lastModified: 1717441840365
}

but i want to access name property. how should i approach? this.videoUrl.name is not working / not getting the file name.

Can you share the request code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
